# Modifying JSON in 2nd window modifies the original JSON in 1st window

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have two windows. In 1st window I have below JSON. I am passing this JSON from 1st window to 2nd window using Alloy.createController("set_schedule", {"data" : data}). In 2nd window I am pushing data to slots, it is modifying the original JOSN of 1st window. I do not want this. It should not modify original data. I have tried storing the args.data to local variable and then manipulating, nothing works.

schedule.js

```
var data = [{
    "day" : "monday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "tuesday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "wednesday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "thursday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "friday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "saturday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "sunday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}] 

var win = Alloy.createController("set_schedule", {
    "data" : data
}).getView("setSchedule");
win.open();
```

set_schedule.js

```
var scheduleData = args.data; //copy to local variable
scheduleData[0].slots.push({"start": "09:00:00",
    "finish": "17:00:00"});
```

Now I close set_schedule window and come back to schedule window it is showing

```
var data = [{
    "day" : "monday",
    "slots" : [{"start": "09:00:00",
    "finish": "17:00:00"}],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "tuesday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "wednesday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "thursday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "friday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "saturday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}, {
    "day" : "sunday",
    "slots" : [],
    "duration" : 0
}]
```

Comment: can you share some code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you're passing is byref because it's an object. What you should do is clone that object to a new json object:

```
var newJsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Note - it might not be the best solution for you (I just don't know what your business logic is).

Answer (score 0):

Would a possible solution be to stringify the JSON as you pass it to the second window and then parse it on the other side.  This would ensure that it is not the same object you are manipulating.

It seems that your code is creating a situation where there is an effective ByRef parameter call (the reference to the object is sent rather than the JSON object itself).